# sum by group inside a looping of list object in java

Tags: java, list, object, for-loop

i've been stuck for creating a subtotal from the list object i have. The Code like this,

```
private List<Object> getData() {
    List<Object> items = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Object> objectList = dataBaseHelper.fetchData();

 for (Object obj : objectList) {
    items.add(new Object(obj.one, obj.two));
 }

return items;

}
```

i can make the list just fine, like

```
a 1
a 2
a 3
b 1
b 2
b 3
```

but i want to make my list like this,

```
    a       1
    a       2
    a       3
subTotal a  6

    b       1
    b       2
    b       3
subTotal b  6
```

can some one guide how i can make that?

Thanks before,

Comment: What actually is the *Class* of `Object` ?

Comment: @kazenorin it just an example, like Car or etc, i give a simple example about my problem, can u give me a hint to achieve what i want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I'll try to answer in a somewhat abstract way.

First to make things less ambiguous, let's assume that `dataBaseHelper.fetchData()` returns a `List<MyObject>` where `MyObject` has the following members:

- `public String name;`
- `public int price;`

Now let's assume we want to calculate the subtotal *grouping by* name. We then need a data structure that can hold data like this. Some simplicity sake, let's just use a Map of Lists:

`Map<String, List<MyObject>> subTotalsByName = new HashMap<>();`

Then we can loop through the returned data:

```
private Map<String, List<MyObject>> getData() {
  Map<String, List<MyObject>> subTotalsByName = new HashMap<>();
  List<MyObject> objectList = dataBaseHelper.fetchData();

  for (MyObject obj : objectList) {
    List<MyObject> subTotalList = subTotalsByName.get(obj.name);
    if (subTotalList == null){
        subTotalList = new ArrayList<>();
        subTotalsByName.put(obj.name, subTotalList);
    }

    subTotalList.add(obj);
  }

  return subTotalsByName;
}
```

*(Note: the above code is untested, treat it as pseudo-code, just to give you an idea of grouping by sub-totals)*

Now you have a `Map` of `List` of `MyObject`s, now you just have to iterate through the map of calculate the subtotals! (In fact, this may be done earlier in the above loop, but to make things clearer, we waste a bit more CPU cycles to explicitly do stuff. It's also a good idea not to do premature optimizations :) )

```
for (Entry<String, List<MyObject>> entry : subTotalsByName.entrySet()) {

  int subtotal = 0;

  List<MyObject> myObjects = entry.getValue();
  for (MyObject myObj : myObjects){
    System.out.println(myObj.name + " " + myObj.price);
    subtotal += myObj.price;
  }

  System.out.println("subTotal for " + entry.getKey() + " is " + subtotal);
  System.out.println();
}
```

*(Again, this is untested, treat as pseudo-code)*

Then you get outputs like this:

```
a 1
a 2
a 3
subTotal for a is 6

b 4
b 5
b 6
subTotal for b is 15
```

Comment: i've been testing it, but i got this error in this line of code

`subTotalsByName.put(subTotalList);`

in my code the error is : put(java.lang.String, List<MyObject>) in Map cannot be applied to (java.util.List<MyObject>)

Comment: It should be`subTotalsByName.put(obj.name, subTotalList);`, as `Map.put(key, value)`requires two parameters

Comment: thanks the code works and it give me the result what i want. Problem is, i don't want to change the other code, because if i change the type of the function from List to Map i need change the other code. It quite excausting, so if any change the type return for the function is still List<MyObject>,  can it be done? or not?

Comment: You mean you don't want to change the return type for `private List<MyObject> getData` at all? If so, it is impossible, or impossible in using normal Java practices. At the very least, you have to change the generic type for List, for example `private List<MyObjectSubtotal> getData`, where MyObjectSubtotal is an object that holds the subtotals. Otherwise, how would you distinguish a aggregate (the subtotal) from a record (the object)?